# Race condition on fixed number of workers pattern

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine, waitgroup

I'm playing with some code for learning purposes and I am getting a race condition on its execution when using the `-race` flag and I want to understand why. The code starts a fixed set of goroutines that act as workers consuming tasks from a channel, there is no fixed number of tasks, as long as the channel receives tasks the workers must keep working.

I'm getting a race condition when calling the `WaitGroup` functions. From what I understand (taking a look at the data race report) the race condition happens when the first `wg.Add` call is executed by one of the spawned goroutines and the main routine calls `wg.Wait` at the same time. Is that correct? If it is, it means that I must always execute calls to Add on the main routine to avoid this kind of race on the resource? But, that also would mean that I need to know how many tasks the workers will need to handle in advance, which kinds of sucks if I need that the code handles any number of tasks that may come once the workers are running...

The code:

```
func Test(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        queuedTaskC := make(chan func())
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            wID := i + 1
            go func(workerID int) {
                for task := range queuedTaskC {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    task()
                }
            }(wID)
        }

        taskFn := func() {
            fmt.Println("executing task...")
            wg.Done()
        }
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn
        queuedTaskC <- taskFn

        wg.Wait()
        close(queuedTaskC)

        fmt.Println(len(queuedTaskC))
    })
}
```

The report:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0001280d8 by goroutine 11:
  internal/race.Read()
      /src/internal/race/race.go:37 +0x206
  sync.(*WaitGroup).Add()
      /src/sync/waitgroup.go:71 +0x219
  workerpool.Test.func1.1()
      /workerpool/workerpool_test.go:36 +0x64

Previous write at 0x00c0001280d8 by goroutine 8:
  internal/race.Write()
      /src/internal/race/race.go:41 +0x125
  sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait()
      /src/sync/waitgroup.go:128 +0x126
  workerpool.Test.func1()
      /workerpool/workerpool_test.go:57 +0x292
  testing.tRunner()
      /src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0x202

Goroutine 11 (running) created at:
  workerpool.Test.func1()
      /workerpool/workerpool_test.go:34 +0xe4
  testing.tRunner()
      /src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0x202

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  testing.(*T).Run()
      /src/testing/testing.go:1168 +0x5bb
  workerpool.Test()
      workerpool_test.go:29 +0x4c
  testing.tRunner()
      /src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0x202
==================
```

Comment: wg.Add must be done _outside_ of the goroutine (i.e. before you launch the goroutine) _allways_. Your code doesn't implement a worker pool at all. The race is just a symptom.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, so hypothetically if I were to have a fixed number of tasks N and I modified this code moving the wg.Add(N) to the main "thread" before launching the goroutines, then I would get rid of the race?

Comment: If you want your test to pass do `go task()` instead of `task()` after `wg.Add(1)` since your `wg.Done()` is getting called inside your task. However, @Volker is right - this is not a worker pool implementation.

Comment: If you have a static number of goroutines, then yes, you can call `Add` with that number. Normally you would just call `Add(1)` immediately before calling `go`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clearing that out, I would like to know why my question was downvoted for future reference, if it was lack of research I assure you that I searched as thoroughly as I could and read the documentation of the sync package but still it wasn't clear enough for me what happened in this example...

Comment: @Kelsnare I tried what you suggested but still get a race condition on some runs

Comment: Fix the structure of the code to get the worker pool working correctly, then make sure you always have `defer wg.Done()` at the start of the goroutine corresponding to `wg.Add`. If that still results in a race, then please submit a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by "get the worker pool working correctly", I would like to know what is wrong with this piece of code and if I have to re-write it altogether or there may be some pieces that could be saved... I've seen a lot of implementations of worker pools that take a fixed number of jobs at the start and then run and distribute them between the workers, what i'm trying to achieve is a worker pool that you can feed once its running with any amount of tasks... Kind of a load balancer but for jobs instead of requests, and without worring about the balancing...

Comment: A worker pool is perfectly fine, you are just confusing the worker pool and the individual tasks with your use of the WaitGroup. Use `wg.Add` for each worker, and `wg.Done` as each returns.

Comment: I think I get it now, you are saying that I'm using the WaitGroup to wait for the tasks to finish and not for the goroutines that execute them, makes sense. I'll try to fix and submit the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WaitGroup` implementation is based on the internal counter which is changed by `Add` and `Done` methods. The `Wait` method will not return until the counter is zeroed. It is also possible to reuse `WaitGroup` but under certain conditions described in the documentation:

```
// If a WaitGroup is reused to wait for several independent sets of events,
// new Add calls must happen after all previous Wait calls have returned.
```

Although your code is not reusing `wg` it's able to zero the `WaitGroup` counter multiple times. This happens when no tasks are being processed at a given time, which is entirely possible in concurrent code. And since your code does not wait `Wait` to return before calling `Add` you get the race condition error.

As everyone suggests in the comments you should abandon the idea of tracking the task with `WaitGroup` in favor of controlling running goroutines. Attaching the code proposal.

```
func Test(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    queuedTaskC := make(chan func(), 10)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wID := i + 1
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(workerID int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for task := range queuedTaskC {
                task()
            }
        }(wID)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        queuedTaskC <- func() {
            fmt.Println("executing task...")
        }
    }
    close(queuedTaskC)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(len(queuedTaskC))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was about to post a similar code but you were faster so I accepted it. Can I ask why you close the channel before calling wg.Wait() and not the other way around?

Comment: If you don't close the channel before wg.Wait, the loop in grourine `for task := range queuedTaskC` will never complete, which cause the goroutine to not call `defer wg.Done()`, which cause the `wg.Wait()` to wait forever. To sum things up we get deadlock.

Comment: So to put it in words, when you close the channel you are "sending a signal" to the workers that no more tasks will be sent to the channel, that ends the for loop for every worker (since there is no more tasks to range) and also the channel being closed won't block their execution.

Comment: To clarify, closing a non-empty channel (buffered channel can contain not received messages) will not end "range" until the channel is empty.

Comment: Exactly, I got it that way but its good to clarify because my explanation may have been rather ambiguous about how that works. Thanks everyone for your help, I learned a lot with this.